# How to realtime plotting firebase data to ChartJS

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, chart.js

I'm having a issue with plotting data on chartjs from firebase data. I have connection with my database, but I can't draw anything on the graph. I want the chart to be automatically refreshed when new data appear in the database. So far I'm trying a simple bar chart.

Can anyone give me a solution?

Firebase node:
[Firebase node:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz8mn.png)

JS:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Value',],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Temperature',
            data: [0],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
    });

 function addData(chart, label, data) {
    chart.data.labels.push(label);
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.push(data);
    });
    chart.update();
    }

function removeData(chart) {
    chart.data.labels.pop();
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.pop();
    });
    chart.update();
}

var config = {
    apiKey: "xxx",
    authDomain: "xxx",
    databaseURL: "xxx",
    projectId: "xxx",
    storageBucket: "xxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxx",
    appId: "xxx",
    measurementId: "xxx"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

var valueRef = firebase.database().ref('temps');
valueRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
    removeData(myChart);
    addData(myChart, "1", snapshot.val());
});
```

EDIT:
I found a solution. Instead of 'values' , it was enough to listen if a new child was added in a relatee node by 'child_added'.

```
var valueRef = firebase.database().ref('temps');
valueRef.on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
    var temperature = snapshot.val().temp;
    var time = snapshot.val().time
    addData(myChart, time, temperature);
});
```

As a result, I recaived a chart of temperature change over time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `onSnapshot` method for subscribe to changes:

```
db.collection("your collection")
     //.where("field", "==", "value")    <--   you can use condition
     //.doc("some document")             <--   or one document
     .onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change) { 
            if (change.type === "added") {
                console.log("New item: ", change.doc.data());
            }
            if (change.type === "modified") {
                console.log("Modified item: ", change.doc.data());
            }
            if (change.type === "removed") {
                console.log("Removed item: ", change.doc.data());
            }
        });
    });
```

[see more examples in docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)

Comment: Thx. You gave me an example of getting data from Cloud Firestore, but I using Realtime Database. It's not the same, is it?

 https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: I'm sorry. Yes it is.